# Double loop vectorization and reshape for Kronecker product in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I've got two matrices

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
a = 2*np.ones((n,n,3))
b = 3*np.ones((n,n,3))
```

I want to multiply them in the way that reminds Kronecker product and then to sum up

```
s = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        s +=  a*b[i,j]
```

Does there exist a method to vectorize it in numpy?

Comment: Is your code correct? `a*b[i,j]` should return an array the same shape as `a`, not a scalar (as suggested by your `s = 0`).

Comment: Yes, it works correctly anyway and `s` is supposed to be the same shape as `a`. But one can write `s = np.zeros((n,n,3))` as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this can be written more elegantly with [`np.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html):

```
import numpy as np


n = 10
a = 2 * np.ones((n, n, 3))
b = 3 * np.ones((n, n, 3))

s = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        s +=  a * b[i, j]

print(s.shape)
# (10, 10, 3)


ss = a * np.einsum('ijk->k', b)
print(ss.shape)
# (10, 10, 3)
print(np.all(s == ss))
# True
```

or even with just `np.sum()`:

```
sss = a * np.sum(b, axis=(0, 1))
print(sss.shape)
# (10, 10, 3)
print(np.all(s == sss))
# True
```

but `np.einsum()` seems to be faster:

```
n = 100
a = 2 * np.ones((n, n, 3))
b = 3 * np.ones((n, n, 3))

%timeit f_with_loops(a, b)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 787 ms per loop
%timeit a * np.einsum('ijk->k', b)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 121 µs per loop
%timeit a * np.sum(b, axis=(0, 1))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 254 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be rewritten as:

[image]

Thus, this should work:

```
s = a * np.sum(np.sum(b,axis=1),axis=0)
```

Comment: Note that this can be written simply as `a * np.sum(b, axis=(0, 1))`

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't even aware of this functionality.